# Webview inside RecyclerVIew to PlayVideo But Sound In background still playing after the fragment destroyed

Tags: android, video, webview, android-recyclerview

I am Using The Web View in side the Recycler View  to play the Video but the problem is i don't know how to stop the video on the fragment destroyed...the sound is still playing in background...please help

```
public class PageVideoAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PageVideoAdapter.MyViewHolder> 
 {
EventPage activity;
ArrayList<PageVideoModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
DisplayMetrics metrics;


public PageVideoAdapter(EventPage activity, ArrayList<PageVideoModel> list) 
 {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_video_adapter, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.titlePageVideoAdapter.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.web.loadUrl(list.get(position).getVideo_url());

    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(list.get(position).getImage_url(),
            new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    holder.imgPageVideoAdapter.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                }
            });

    holder.imgPageVideoAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setOpen(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (list.get(position).isOpen == true) {
        holder.imgPageVideoAdapter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.imgPageVideoAdapter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void clearData() {
    list.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<PageVideoModel> list) {
    this.list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @InjectView(R.id.title_PageVideoAdapter)
    TextView titlePageVideoAdapter;
    @InjectView(R.id.img_PageVideoAdapter)
    ImageView imgPageVideoAdapter;
    @InjectView(R.id.fl_PageVideoAdapter)
    FrameLayout flPageVideoAdapter;
    @InjectView(R.id.web)
    WebView web;


    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "AddJavascriptInterface"})
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);

        titlePageVideoAdapter.setTypeface(AppClass.typeface_roboto_regular);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsOne = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, (metrics.heightPixels * 340) / 800);
        flPageVideoAdapter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsOne);

        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (web != null) {
                    web.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        web.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void resize(final float height) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                web.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
            }
        });
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you update any sample code... question is clear but if we see your code we can solve it... Update your Code in question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean,but you can try the adapter Override `onViewAttachedToWindow` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow`.

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    //start playing
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    //stop play
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are Playing Video form Web-view

then Use this at onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
myWebView.destroy();
myWebView = null;
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Please Update your sample Code if problem is not solved...

I will Update my Answer if you update your Question

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet when you destroy your fragment, it works for me.

**1) Suggestion 1:**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    wView.onPause();
    wView.pauseTimers();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    wView.resumeTimers();
    wView.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    wView.destroy();
    wView= null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Suggestion 2:**

```
wView.loadUrl(""); // passing blank param in this method will stop playing.
```

Give it a try...

Comment: But The Problem is WebView is not in fragment....it is in The RecyclerVIew

Comment: Ohhh I see, then try with @dengyuhan's solution, I think that's gonna solve your problem